# Cannot open source file "SDKDDKVer.h" in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I was using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and recently I uninstall the old one and install the Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Then now I fail to run a C++ hello world for the error: `Cannot open source file "SDKDDKVer.h"`

Can anyone tell me how may I correct my source file path for this problem? All existed problems seem not working for me.

Comment: I searched my filesystem and in 20 seconds I had 3 results. The most likely is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared` Although I am not using Visual Studio 2015. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

Comment: I repair it in control panel and it's fine now, I guess it's because i was offline when installed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to `repair` the Visual Studio from the control panel and everything is fine now.

The installing process need network connection, if some period of the installing process is offline, some configuration errors may occur.